# Turning string If statement to a Java IF statement

Tags: java, string, escaping

I need to turn a string such as

```
class freud IF : 0.010<=cst0.1<=0.02 ^ 0.012<=cst0.2<=0.014 ^ 0.01<=cst0.3<=0.011 ^ 0.009<=cst0.4<=0.01 ^ cst0.5=0.009 ^ 0.008<=cst0.6<=0.009 ^ 0.008<=cst0.7<=0.009 ^ 0.007<=cst0.8<=0.009 ^ 0.007<=cst0.9<=0.009 ^ 0.008<=cst1.0<=0.012
```

into an actual Java if statement: i.e.

```
if(0.010 <= cst0.1 && cst0.1 <= 0.02 .....)
```

where cst0.1 becomes the name of a float etc.

Any ideas? I have tried splitting the string into its components, but all the strings I need vary!

Thanks

Comment: You need a grammar for your freud IF statement.  Parse it into an AST and then walk the tree to generate a Java IF statement.

Comment: Is there an underlying syntax to the string? You may need a parser. You could look at JavaCC, but I hear it has a steep learning curve.

Comment: @S.L.Barth There is an underlying syntax in terms it uses '<=', '=' and teh attributes, which are 'cst0.1' etc. But in terms of a pattern then you can also get a string such as  `code`class freud IF : cst0.1=0.024 ^ cst0.2=0.018 ^ cst0.3=0.016 ^ cst0.4=0.014 ^ cst0.5=0.013 ^ cst0.6=0.012 ^ cst0.7=0.011 ^ cst0.8=0.011 ^ cst0.9=0.01 ^ cst1.0=0.013  (1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try create evaluate method `boolean evaluate(String stringToEvaluate)`
wich will split your string on segments and evaluate each bit

```
public class MyClass {
    public boolean evaluate(String stringToEvaluate)
    {
    boolean exprvalue = true;
    for (String string : stringToEvaluate.split("^"))
            {
            exprvalue = exprvalue && evaluateLE(string);
            }
    return exprvalue;
    }

    private boolean evaluateLE(String string) {
        String[] values = string.split("<=");
        if (values.length==2)
        {
            return evaluateVal(values[0]) <= evaluateVal(values[1]); 
        }

        return evaluateOtherLogicalExpr(string);
    }

    private float evaluateVal(String string) {
        if (isExpresion(string)) return evaluateArthmeticalExpr(string);
        if (isVariable(string)) return evaluateVariable(string);

        return Float.parseFloat(string);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow your's is much neater than mine! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From what you show it should be sufficient to replace the dot with a valid identifier character, e.g. `_`, in strings of the form `cstX.Y` where X and Y are digits, and to replace `^` with `&&`.

For the resulting if statement to be valid you should also declare all the `cstX_Y` variables you introduced.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have an answer. Here are my steps and then code:

1. Identify if line has IF in it
2. If it does, then split line into equality components using split(" ^ ") - this will vary on the structure.
3. Now check in each component, check if there is an equality "<=", "="
4. handle each independently according to structure.
5. convert each "0.025" (for example) to a float
6. create JAVA if statement based on 3,5 and the data you want to compare it against.
7. Record as going along if all equalities hold throughout line. If one fails, break away, get new line. If all holds function returns initial value i.e. Artist string.

Anyway here is the code:

```
while(line != null ){
            boolean equality = false;

            String[] split_line;
            String[] first_part;
            String[] statements;
            String[] components;

            if(line.contains("IF")){
                split_line = line.split(":");
                statements = split_line[1].split(" ^ ");
                int attrib_pos = 0;

                for(int pos = 0; pos < statements.length; pos++){
                    if(statements[pos].contains("<=")){
                        components = statements[pos].split("<=");
                        float component_1 = new Float(components[0]);
                        // middle component is attribute
                        float component_2 = new Float(components[2]);

                        if(!(( component_1 <= data[attrib_pos]) && (data[attrib_pos] <= component_1))){
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    else if(statements[pos].contains("=") ){
                        components = statements[pos].split("=");
                        float component_1 = new Float(components[1]);
                        if(!(component_1 == data[attrib_pos])){
                            break;
                    }
                        // if we have not found a false statement, increase no of attributes which hold
                        attrib_pos++;
                }
                }
                // if we have run through all attributes as holding then return, as we have found a true rule
                if(attrib_pos-1 == statements.length){
                    _return = (split_line[0].split("\\s+"))[2];
                    return _return;
                }
            }
            // once we have read the line, read another 
        line = read.readLine();

        }               
    }
```